# How do I get access to the Tortoise Hg Shell (hgtk) on Windows XP?

Tags: mercurial, windows-xp, tortoisehg

I tried using hgtk on my machine after installing Tortoise Hg, but the command isn't recognised. I then browsed the to Tortoise folder, but couldn't find any executable hgtk. How can I access this command line interface on Windows XP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>If you are using a TortoiseHg binary install, hgtk.exe is already installed and in your path.</strike>

https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/wiki/hgtk

Edit:

hgtk has been removed from TortoiseHg as of 2.0

```
Development for PyQt based TortoiseHg 2.0 (March 1, 2011) is happening at: 

http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/

At the 2.0 release, the thg repo will become the official TortoiseHg repository, 
and stable will be removed. The hgtk tool will be kept and maintained for as long as
it has users. But we may release installers for it infrequently or not at all.
```

https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/wiki/developers/repositories